# How to check that all shards are moved from a specific elasticsearch node?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-migration, kubernetes-cluster

I'm trying to move all the shards (primary and copies) from one specific elasticsearch node to others.

While doing some studies, I came to know about [Cluster-level shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-filtering.html) where I can specify the node name which I want to ignore while allocating shards.

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : "data-node-1"
  }
}
```

My questions are,

1. If I dynamically update the setting, will the shards be moved from the nodes that I excluded to other nodes automatically?
2. How can I check and make sure that all shards are moved from a specific node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, your shards will be moved automatically, *if it is possible to do so*:

   > Shards are only relocated if it is possible to do so without breaking another routing constraint, such as never allocating a primary and replica shard on the same node.

   More information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-filtering.html)
2. You can use the [shards api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html) to see the location of all shards. Alternatively, if you have access to a kibana Dashboard, you can see the shard allocation in the monitoring tab for shards or indices at the very bottom.

Comment: Thanks. Another question, Is there a way to confirm that this move operation will not be successful because it breaks the routing constraint?

Comment: I don't think so. But unless you have fewer new nodes than replica (which wouldn't make much sense), you probably won't have to worry about that.